# Is there any ECB (or other)-enhanced find file mojo?

Tags: emacs, ido, emacs-ecb

Can I use [ECB](http://ecb.sourceforge.net/) (or some other project aware thing, like [eproject](http://wiki.github.com/jrockway/eproject/), [ibuffer](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/IbufferMode), etc.) to enhance emacs's `find-file` goodness?

Imagine this scenario: I have several projects/directories specified in my `ecb-source-path`, let's call them Project1 and Project2, and they look like so:

```
Project1
  foo.c
  bar.c

Project2
  foo.c
  baz.c
```

I'd like to have `find-file` (or another command) work to find and jump to the files there without having to navigate to the ecb directories buffer, or have the buffers open already.

I guess my ideal usage scenario would be like so:

I'd like to `C-x C-f baz` (or another special command) to open `Project2/baz.c`. Going even further, I'd love if I could use something like [ido](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/InteractivelyDoThings)'s flex matching to get `p2foo` open `Project2/foo.c`.

¿C'est posible?

Comment: *Everything* is possible in Emacs. You just need to find a butterfly.

Comment: @Paul: I guess I was hoping that someone else has already seen this particular butterfly and could point me in the direction that I might find it ... :-)

Answer (score 2):

If in your example you are in project1 foo.c, and you want to get to project1 bar.c, I think most of the project tools like ede, eproject, gnu global, idutils integration etc have "jump to file" type commands.  I, of course, recommend the CEDET/EDE and ECB combination.  The keybinding is `C-c . f` which is `ede-find-file`.

Setting up CEDET and EDE is pretty easy, but EDE knows only a small number of different project types, and you may need to configure it for your projects by hand which is less easy.

If you want to be in project1/foo.c and jump to project2/baz.c, you just need to use locate:

```
M-x locate RET baz.c RET
```

Now select from the list.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [filecache](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/File-Name-Cache.html) package to index the directories you want, then use ido to choose a filename from the cache.  [Here](http://sachachua.com/blog/2009/01/emacs-file-cache-and-ido/) is one example; there are other implementations you can Google for.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [find-file-in-project](http://github.com/bbatsov/find-file-in-project). It seems to me you're looking for something similar.

Answer (score 2):

I've written a package [find-file-in-tags](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/find-file-in-tags) which enables you to open files in your [TAGS](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/TagsFile) file without specifying the path to the file.  If there are multiple files that match what you've entered, you're prompted to refine your choice (or open all).

Additionally, if you have multiple work areas for the same project, `find-file-in-tags` uses a single TAGS file for all those work areas but opens up the file in the same work area as the buffer in which you are invoking `find-file-in-tags`.